# What is the fastest way to trim blank lines from beginning and end of array?

Tags: php, string, arrays, trim

This script:

```
<?php

$lines[] = '';
$lines[] = 'first line   ';
$lines[] = 'second line ';
$lines[] = '';
$lines[] = 'fourth line';
$lines[] = '';
$lines[] = '';

$lineCount = 1;
foreach($lines as $line) {
    echo $lineCount . ': [' . trim($line) . ']<br/>'; 
    $lineCount++;
}

?>
```

produces this output:

```
1: []
2: [first line]
3: [second line]
4: []
5: [fourth line]
6: []
7: []
```

What is the fastest, most efficient way to change the above script so that it also deletes the **preceding** and **trailing** blank entries but **not the interior** blank entries so that it outputs this:

```
1: [first line]
2: [second line]
3: []
4: [fourth line]
```

I could use the foreach loop but I imagine there is a way with array_filter or something similar which is much more efficient.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's `array_slice` to create the trimmed array.

```
function trimLines($lines) {
    $end = count($lines);
    for ($start=0; $lines[$start] === ''; ++$start) {
        if ($start == $end) {
            return array();
        }
    }
    do { --$end; } while ($lines[$end] === '');
    return array_slice($lines, $start, $end-$start+1);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
// find the first non-blank line
$size = count($lines);
while ($lines[$i] === '' && $i < $size) {
  $i++;
}
$start = $i;

// find the last non-blank line
$i = $size;
while ($lines[$i - 1] === '' && $i > $start) {
  $i--;
}
$end = $i;

// traverse between the two    
for ($i=$start; $i<$end; $i++) {
  echo ($i + $start) . ': [' . trim($lines[$i]) . ']<br/>';
}
```